# Alignment of items from navbar

Tags: html, css

In my recent project, I have an view named index.html with a code like this:

```
  <body>
      <header>
        <ul>
          <li><a th:href="@{/}" class="title">Loja</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">blablabla</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">blablabla</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">blablabla</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="right">
          <li><a href="#" class="user"/>username</li>
          <li><a th:href="@{/admin}">admin</a></li>
          <li><a th:href="@{/logout}">logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </header>
  </body>
```

the css style for the header is like that:

```
header ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

header ul.right {
  float:right;
}

header li {
  float: left;
}

header li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Oxygen Mono';
}

header li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}

header li.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

When I open this page in the browser, the items placed on the right side are being display in another line (see: https://jsfiddle.net/klebermo/ch6gtj3p/). Anyone knows what I could change in the css for fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the left menu bar isn't floated. You should add:

```
header ul {
    float: left;
}
```

And set the background color of the `header` tag instead:

```
header {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: this fix the alignment but separate the two parts (see the updated code here: https://jsfiddle.net/klebermo/ch6gtj3p/1/)

Comment: You can fix that by giving `<header>` a background color.

Comment: and about place the items horizontally, instead vertically, like it is now?

Comment: `header li { float:left }`, but you should have left that untouched. You need both `ul` and `li` to be floated.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed display:block for the  header li a and it looks aligned .

codepen URL for reference

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vKOwxQ

```
                header li a {

            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-family: 'Oxygen Mono';
        }
```

Hope this is helpful for you